# Changing local coordinate system to WGS84 in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer

I have composed a map where shapefiles, points etc. all are in local coordinate system (l-est).

Is it possible to convert it to common WGS84 system?

So that in printed map there are coordinates `23.906250;59.432234` (not local `6506050; 4534232`)?

I've tried to change it under items properties -> the CRS selector, but no luck.

At the moment in "QGIS print composer" I have this picture:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. An example image of how you currently incorporate the coordinates in your layout would be helpful in order to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, here is the picture.
https://i.ibb.co/sFHBFrF/Untitled2.png

Comment: Feel free to [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/320842/edit) your post so it contains the image ;-)

Comment: PolyGeo just deleted my picture from the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In Printcomposer go to `Item Properties` and scroll down to `Grids`
2. Modify your existing grid or create a new one and modify this one

[image]

3. At the top (in appearance) you can change the coordinate system of your grid:

[image]

Choose a fitting Interval.

In case you want to to change the projection of your map, you need to do this in your main project:

[image]